# using wheelzoom in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

bonjour
excuse  my bad english
I want to zoom an image in colorbox, i try to use whelzoom without iframe,
the image is correctly displayed in colorbox but wheelzoom don't run
I use  code like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
    <title>test wheelzoom</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.23.1" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="wheelzoom.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 // <!-- <![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.thickbox").colorbox({
   maxWidth: "98%",
   maxHeight: "98%",
   photo: true,
   onComplete:function(){
       // $("#image.thickbox").wheelzoom(); =>> error wheelzoom is not a function
       wheelzoom(document.querySelector ('a.thickbox'));
      },
   close: 'fermer'
  });
   
 });
 // ]]> -->
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/colorbox.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="image">
  <a href="images/DSC00780.JPG" class="thickbox" title="DSC00780"> <img class='zoom' src='images/DSC00780.JPG' alt=' ' width='580'  /></a>
  <script type="text/javascript">wheelzoom(document.querySelector('img.zoom'), {zoom:0.10});</script> <!-- thumbnail, zoom running correctly -->
 </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

could someone help me
thanks
rb

Comment: I found the solution:onComplete:function(){
   wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
},

Comment: thanks for the answer bill!